# Шестиугольник в svg с изображением

Tags: css, svg

Есть два `svg` с изображением внутри, но во ***2-ом*** `svg` у изображения другой размер, из-за этого ***2-ой*** `svg` преобразуется в восьмиугольник.

Как можно этого избежать, чтобы изображение корректно адаптировалось под размер блока, чтобы был постоянно шестиугольник?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
     <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/7d407d/ffffff" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
   </defs>
   <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
     <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/7d407d/ffffff" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
   </defs>
   <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img1)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djx4zaou/

Comment: Попробуйте задать полигону t`ransform="scale(0.5)"` или увеличьте размеры картинки уже в svg

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, ничего не поменялось  https://jsfiddle.net/2g9obsm6/

Comment: к сожалению jsfiddle не работает у меня на телефоне..

Comment: тогда сделайте x="-50" width="200", но через scale тоже можно, только для паттерна тогда надо указать атрибут

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternContentUnits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы картинка полностью влезала в SVG  применяют атрибут `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

ваш код: https://jsfiddle.net/tzfk6ea1/

[Справочная информация по изменения aspectRatio у изображений в SVG на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Собственно дэмо на лицо

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/7d407d/ffffff" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
  </svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/7d407d/ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon   points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img1)"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: в вашем примере видно, что изображение по высоте растянулось. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы было не растягивалось?

Comment: @word вы же сами намеренно изменили размер изображения, 100x50 задали вопрос  `изображение корректно адаптировалось под размер блока` и я ответил как ..что не устроило ?

Comment: @word из прямоугольника сделать квадрат красиво на автомате не возможно

Comment: @word  [ссылка на скриншот](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ascmkyufw6oxzyf/SC.png)  видите что это всё равно квадрат а ваше изображение прямоугольное и естественно его растягивает по высоте то что вы и хотели

Comment: тогда как можно вообще сделать, чтобы был шестиугольник, и внутри изображение корректно отображалось? Может тут можно обойтись обычным div?

Comment: использовать правильный AspectRatio если svg object квадрат то и использовать квадратное изображение , если портретный svg object использовать портретную картинку и т д всего три вида объектов в HTML  это квадрат, праямоугольник - портретный и альбомный и всё

Comment: @word  вот смотри : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000728/308951  жди ответа ..надеюсь минусами не запинают