# Можно ли на javascript узнать aspectRatio изображения?

Tags: javascript, svg

К примеру имеем svg , любой объект на странице либо прямоугольник либо квадрат,
так вот для примера взять pattern svg в котором я хочу без ошибочно что бы изображение было на весь pattern и не было растянуто!

SVG взят с какого то вопроса на stackoverflow как пример моего вопроса где применяются разные изображения

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/7d407d/ffffff" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
  </svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/7d407d/ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon   points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img1)"/>
  </svg>
```

В этом случае надо программно определить aspectRatio изображения что бы увеличить pattern под правильный размер, ведь изображения могут быть :

1) портретные

2) альбомные

3) квадратные

Можно ли средствами javascript это узнать и написать верный параметр pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное нужно указать `preserveAspectRatio` другой, например `xMidYMid slice`

[Вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) можно наглядно посмотреть как работает этот параметр

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="90vh">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/200x100" 
             width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img1)"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="90vh">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/100x200" 
             width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img2)"/>
</svg>
```

---

PS: чтобы программно узнать портретное изображение квадратное или альбомное нужно его скачать и сравнить ширину на высоту

```js
let images = ['https://dummyimage.com/20x30', 'https://dummyimage.com/30x20', 'https://dummyimage.com/30x30']

images.forEach(url => {

  let img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = e => console.log(url, getAspectRatio(img))

})

function getAspectRatio(img){
  if (img.width > img.height) 
    return "landscape"
  if (img.width < img.height) 
    return "portrait" 
  return "square" 
}
```

Comment: а если автоматически определить надо ? и к тому же тоже растянуто

Comment: не растянуто а обрезано и увеличено

Comment: автоматически определить надо

Comment: добавил вторую svg там обратная пропорция

Comment: и всё же вопрос был в другом

Comment: @MaximLensky узнать размеры можно только скачав изображение и спросив фактический размер у элемента (тэг img)

Comment: не размер - а его пространственное положение

Comment: портретное альбомное или квадратное

Comment: @MaximLensky это узнаешь если разделишь ширину на высоту

Comment: в общем aspectRatio узнать

Comment: ща дополню ответ

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MMzEyP  так ?

Comment: @MaximLensky я дополнил ответ, просто `img.width` и `img.height`

Comment: а new Image для чего ?

Comment: @MaximLensky  это тот же img,ток так короче синтаксис https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: @MaximLensky это раньше не было forEach у NodeList

Answer (score 4):

https://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img')

if (img.naturalWidth) {
  console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)
} else {
  img.onload = () => console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)
}
```

```css
html, body, img { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; display: block; }
```

```html
<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5oHxs.png?s=328&g=1">
```

Comment: только автор хотел соотношение сторон, плюс заочно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну соотношение сторон из их длин легко получается. А что значит заочно? А вот из svg что-то такое не ковыряется.

Comment: ну в надежде что деление добавишь, в свг так не получится, точнее я не вмтречал способа